# Anonymous page - Intranet SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to create an anonymous page in SharePoint Intranet Site. All rest of the site is using windows claims authentication but I want to create single page which should be anonymous.

I believe there is a way to create a page in IIS under layouts directory and it can be accessible anonymously but I am not able to make it work. Anybody has any idea?

Editing it with the code I have so far

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase" DynamicMasterPageFile="~/_layouts/15/ErrorV15.master" %>

 <HTML>
   <script runat="server" language="C#">
      protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
    {    get{ return true; } }
    protected override bool AllowNullWeb     
        {        get { return true; } }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     

        }


   </script>
   <body>
      <form id="MyForm" runat="server">
           Application page
      </form>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, you shouldn't change any files manually.

You should start with a SharePoint form solution project in your Visual Studio and it will produce a WSP file. By installing it, the SharePoint platform will place it in the correct location (psst, the 15 hive).

In that project, you'll need to add an application page and it needs to inherit from [`UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.unsecuredlayoutspagebase.aspx) and override the `AllowAnonymousAccess` property, returning true.

Comment: Thanks Rubens for replying. I have created a page with below code but it's still giving authentication access:                                                                                                                                                            public partial class ApplicationPage1: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
{
     
    protected override bool AllowAnnonymouseAccess
 {   get{ return true; } }
 protected override bool AllowNullWeb     
    {    get { return true; } }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         }
}

Comment: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013.html ?

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to enable anonymous access for the whole site. It's an intranet portal so every user should be authenticated but I would like to create few pages which are anonymous.

Comment: I think you will need to enable it; you can later remove the anonymous user permission

Comment: I am still not sure how temporarily enabling anonymous access at the web application/site level will help here.

Comment: Try it: you need to _add_ the anonymous _authentication_ and, later, _remove_ the access from the _anonymous user_.